# Multiple Lines column adding extra lines automatically

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, multiple-lines-of-text

I have a multiple lines column and when I use workflow to send it's value via email, it's adding an extra row in the beggining and in the end of the string. If I have only 1 line, it becomes 3. I tried adding a trim action to the variable containing the value but it didn't work. What could it be?

Comment: Is your multiple lines column plain text, rich text, or enhanced rich text?

Comment: It is Enhanced Rich Text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple lines fields of the type rich text or enhanced rich text add html paragraph tags before and after the content. So you can either change your field to plain text, or change the `Return field as` of your field to `plain text` in the workflow.

Comment: Returning as plain text worked. Thank you Erin, I like your answers. Straight and correct. You know how to get things done!
    Hope I'll be able to count on you on the future, because in this entire year I'll have to learn alot of Sharepoint.